# Proving a factorial equation through simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Okay, so I am rather new to factorials so I don't know all the rules and simplifications, but what I do know is the following:

$(n)! = (n)(n-1)!$

$(2n)!=(2n)(2n−1)!$

However, I need to show the following:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!} + \frac{(2n)!}{(n-2)!(n+2)!} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n-1)!(n+2)!}$$

Comment: Have you tried getting a common denominator for the fractions on the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!} + \frac{(2n)!}{(n-2)!(n+2)!} = \frac{(2n)!(n+2)}{(n-1)!(n+2)!} + \frac{(2n)!(n-1)}{(n-1)!(n+2)!} $$

$$=\frac{(2n)!((n+2)+(n-1))}{(n-1)!(n+2)!}=\frac{(2n)!(2n+1)}{(n-1)!(n+2)!}$$